# Reading and Parsing a csv in node.js on a local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to open a csv file that I have stored locally on my node server, from my web app (and in the browser - for testing purposes).

its an express server and but when i try to access/open file in browser VIA absolute path, i get "cannot get filepath error". Im not sure why I cant get the file, when the path is correct.

the file path looks like this `http://localhost:8000/files/7e911083-d12c-e5f9-10d7-db8e5e955c51.csv` and my server is ON.

how do i view csvs in browser? let alone accessing from web app. thanks

Comment: You have supplied none of your server code, if you want to get accurate help on SO, you should. Always supply code whenever relevant.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick instructions To get the file into node and then parse it into json.**

---

Example CSV file: ../THEPATHINYOURPROJECT/TOTHE/csv_FILE_YOU_WANT_TO_LOAD.csv

```
ABC, 123, Fudge
532, CWE, ICECREAM
8023, POOP, DOGS
441, CHEESE, CARMEL
221, ABC, HOUSE
```

---

**1. Install CSV node module using the following command:**

```
npm install csv
```

**2. Then in your app.js add the following code (the comments are just to explain function)**

```
var csv = require('csv'); 
// loads the csv module referenced above.


var obj = csv(); 
// gets the csv module to access the required functionality


function MyCSV(Fone, Ftwo, Fthree) {
    this.FieldOne = Fone;
    this.FieldTwo = Ftwo;
    this.FieldThree = Fthree;
}; 
// Define the MyCSV object with parameterized constructor, this will be used for storing the data read from the csv into an array of MyCSV. You will need to define each field as shown above.


var MyData = []; 
// MyData array will contain the data from the CSV file and it will be sent to the clients request over HTTP. 


obj.from.path('../THEPATHINYOURPROJECT/TOTHE/csv_FILE_YOU_WANT_TO_LOAD.csv').to.array(function (data) {
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        MyData.push(new MyCSV(data[index][0], data[index][1], data[index][2]));
    }
    console.log(MyData);
});
//Reads the CSV file from the path you specify, and the data is stored in the array we specified using callback function.  This function iterates through an array and each line from the CSV file will be pushed as a record to another array called MyData , and logs the data into the console to ensure it worked.


var http = require('http');
//Load the http module.


var server = http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    resp.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'application/json' });
    resp.end(JSON.stringify(MyData));
});
// Create a webserver with a request listener callback.  This will write the response header with the content type as json, and end the response by sending the MyData array in JSON format.

server.listen(8080);
// Tells the webserver to listen on port 8080(obviously this may be whatever port you want.)
```

**3. After we create this app.js file open a console, and type the following command**

```
Node app
```

4. **This will show the following result**

```
    [  MYCSV { Fone: 'ABC', Ftwo: '123', Fthree: 'Fudge' },
       MYCSV { Fone: '532', Ftwo: 'CWE', Fthree: 'ICECREAM' },
       MYCSV { Fone: '8023', Ftwo: 'POOP, Fthree: 'DOGS' },
       MYCSV { Fone: '441', Ftwo: 'CHEESE', Fthree: 'CARMEL' },
       MYCSV { Fone: '221', Ftwo: 'ABC', Fthree: 'HOUSE' }, ]
```

**5. Now, Open your webbrowser and enter the following URL into the address bar: http://127.0.0.1:8080
and you should see the result in your browser displayed in JSON format.**

I hope this helps.

---

If your app is completely unable to access the file I would first double check your permissions, and that it is inside of the project, and in the location specified.

Comment: I want to parse it client side, i just cant "get" it.

Comment: Can you post me the code that you're trying to use to get it?

Comment: I changed my answer to have instructions and code, and explained how it works.

Comment: This will put it into a json array and you can parse that out client or server side.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but you routed the path in your nodejs app? e.g. in your app.js:

```
app.get('files/*.csv',function(req,res){
    //call req.url for required csv
    res.sendfile(PATH_TO_CSV/CSV.csv)
})
```

edit: how the browser choose to display csv file, after it receives the file, might be unpredictable. as such, it's probably easier to parse the csv file on the server side, and send json obj instead of csv file.